# no member named 'array' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, ubuntu-16.04

I am learning C++ right now and i get this somewhat weird error.

The Code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
using std::array;

template <typename T, size_t dim>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const array<T,dim>& a) {
    os << "[ ";
    for (auto n : a)
        os << n << " ";
    os << "]";
    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << endl << "--- " << __FILE__ << " ---" << endl << endl;

    array<int,3> a1 { 2,3,5 };                              // (A)
    array<int,0> a2 {  };                                   // (B)
    array<int,2> a3 { 1 };                                  // (C)
    // array<int> x1 { 1, 2, 3 };                           // (D)
    // array<int,3> x2 { 1,2,3,4 };
    array<int,3> a4 = { 1,2,3 };                            // (E)
    array<int,3> a5 { { 4,5,6 } };                          // (F)

    cout << "01|    a1=" << a1 << endl;
    cout << "02|    a2=" << a2 << endl;
    cout << "03|    a3=" << a3 << endl;
    cout << "04|    a4=" << a4 << endl;
    cout << "05|    a5=" << a5 << endl;

    cout << endl << "--- " << __FILE__ << " ---" << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My IDE (Visual Studio Code) shows me the error, although the code is compiling and working.

Here is the makefile provided by our Prof.

```
# compiler settings
CXX = g++-7
# CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pthread -std=c++17
LDFLAGS = -lm

# collect  files
CXXEXAMPLES = $(shell find . -name '*.cpp' -print -type f)
CXXTARGETS = $(foreach file, $(CXXEXAMPLES), ./out/$(file:.cpp=.out))

# build them all
all: $(CXXTARGETS)

out/%.out: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)  $< $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
    rm out/*
```

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and thought it might be a compiler problem, so I changed "CXX" to "CXX = g++-7", because we were recommended to use g++ Version 7 but it didn't helped.
On typing "g++ -v" it shows that my gcc is version 5.5.0, but typing "apt list -installed" shows that g++-7 is installed.

I did not find any solution on the internet as most similar problems often revolved around missing includes.

VS Code also does not recognize some types of variable definitions like 
"int n{1}"
It also complains about the "use of undeclared identifier" on the lines (A) to (E)

I assume the problem lies within the VS Code compiler using a different/old syntax recognition. But I don't know how to change that.

Comment: Have you configured VSC to understand C++17?

Comment: Pass `-std=c++17` to the compiler to enable C++17. And read the manual "man g++" or https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/

Comment: @JesperJuhl It is already in the makefile.

Comment: If it compiles, it is a Warning _only_ ...

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I just googled for that and found out about a c_cpp_properties.json file.

I guess this might be important
"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
"cStandard": "c11",
"cppStandard": "c++17",
"intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"

Where can I configure VSC to understand C++17?